# Correct way to Terraform template_provider data source output

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I'm trying to render the output of a map using a template in Terraform:
     
     `variable "default_tags" {
      type = "map"
      default = {
       "tag1" ="Tag A",
       "tag2" ="Tag B"
      }
     }`

Define a template_file data source to render the map:

````
```
data "template_file" "test" {
  template = "${data}"
  vars {
    data = "${join(",", formatlist("key: %s, val: %s. ",     keys(var.default_tags), values(var.default_tags)))}"
  }
}
```
````

My output bloc should look like this:

````
```
 output "default_tags_rendered" {
  value="${data.template_file.test.rendered}"
 }
```
````

However I get this error when planning:

````
 ```
 Error: data.template_file.test: 1 error(s) occurred:
 * data.template_file.test: invalid variable syntax: "data". Did you mean      'var.data'? If this is part of inline `template` parameter
 then you must escape the interpolation with two dollar signs. For
 example: ${a} becomes $${a}.
 ```
````

What would be the correct way to output the rendered template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be better suited to using [local values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) like so

```
locals {
  data = "${join(",", formatlist("key: %s, val: %s. ", keys(var.default_tags), values(var.default_tags)))}"
}

output "default_tags_rendered" {
 value="${local.data}"
}
```

Reasoning is because the [template_file provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html) is mainly used for files (or inline templates) that need to be run through the standard interpolation syntax. In this case, you don't have any variables to be interpolated in a template - you have a variable coming in and you need to mutate it's value.